# What is the difference between System.Drawing.Color and System.Windows.Media.Color?

Tags: .net

Basically, why the need for two abstractions of a pretty simple concept?

Comment: WPF vs Window Forms.  Two UI layers, two sets of definitions.

Comment: To confound this further, I've noticed that the Brush type properties in WPF/Silverlight choose values in the designer from System.Drawing.Color (which are unavailable in System.Windows.Media.Color), despite this namespace being unavailable to Silverlight.

Comment: What confounds me further is that System.Drawing.Color has way more functionality in its methods (e.g. FromArgb have various overloads) than does System.Windows.Media.Color.

Comment: The enum / list of all colors have actually different names: System.Drawing.Color vs System.Windows.Media.Color**s** !
The Drawing.Color have more features, e.g. a Name property. For instance, System.Drawing.Color.Blue.Name should be similar to nameof(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue)
But the  System.Windows.Media.Color (without 's') class contains also the static methods as FromArgb but with less overloads)

Comment: A very unfortunate further development is that UWP and .NET Standard use System.Drawing.Color.  You might have thought that Media.Color being more recent would have replaced Drawing.Color.  Not the case.  It appears that Media.Color is being orphaned.  Bad news for folks building libraries common to WPF and UWP.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`System.Windows.Media.Color` is part of the [`System.Windows.Media`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.aspx) namespace:

> Provides types that enable integration of rich media, including drawings, text, and audio/video content in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications.

`System.Drawing.Color` is part of the [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace:

> The System.Drawing namespace provides access to GDI+ basic graphics functionality. More advanced functionality is provided in the System.Drawing.Drawing2D, System.Drawing.Imaging, and System.Drawing.Text namespaces.

I'm guessing that the latter is Windows specific, whilst the former is more general and is more easily portable to Mac OS etc. for use in Silverlight applications.

There is also this caution on the latter namespace which would tend to support this:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.

Comment: While technically true, it doesn't answer the more fundamental question of why Microsoft decided the concept of color had to be linked into graphics.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there was a "need" as such, just that they made an early (probably wrong) decision to put the Color class into the the WinForms-specific System.Drawing - because at the time, Win32 and Winforms was all there was.

Later when they wanted to enhance the concepts in "Color", they didn't want WPF to depend on WinForms. So rather than fix the situation by moving a more abstract Color class to a generic assembly, they just copy-pasted a new Color class in WPF.