# Set System.Drawing.Color values

Tags: c#, .net, colors, immutability, system.drawing.color

Hi how to set `R G B` values in `System.Drawing.Color.G` ?

which is like `System.Drawing.Color.G=255;` is not allowed because its read only

```
Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Color.G' cannot be assigned toit is read only
```

i just need to create a `Color` Object by assigning custom `R G B` values

Comment: Note for others that come to this question, this problem only affects System.Drawing. If you're using WPF you should be using System.Windows.Media For more info see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428930/what-is-the-difference-between-system-drawing-color-and-system-windows-media-col

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You could create a color using the static [FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx) method:

```
Color redColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```

You can also specify the alpha using the [following overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh.aspx).

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 13):

The `Color` structure is **immutable** (as all structures should really be), meaning that the values of its properties cannot be changed once that particular instance has been created.

Instead, you need to create a *new* instance of the structure with the property values that you want. Since you want to create a color using its component RGB values, you need to use the [`FromArgb` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dy2fb2e.aspx):

```
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 150, 75);
```

Comment: -1 for "as all structures should really be". Good luck writing some C code.

Comment: @Dariusz I don't see a [c] tag on this question. I write C code all the time, I just don't write it the same way as I do my C# code...

Answer (score 10):

You must use Color.FromArgb method to create new color structure

```
var newColor = Color.FromArgb(0xCC,0xBB,0xAA);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make extension to just change one color component

```
static class ColorExtension
{
    public static Color ChangeG(Color this color,byte g) 
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(color.A,color.R,g,color.B);
    }
}
```

then you can use this:

```
  yourColor = yourColor.ChangeG(100);
```

Comment: Yeah, but don't do this. It hides the fact that you're actually creating a new instance of the structure, very confusing for someone who doesn't already understand immutability. And fairly useless for someone who does.

Comment: First of all you **NEED** to understand immutability. Code becomes uglier if you will write `yourColor = Color.FromArgb(yourColor.A,yourColor.R,100,yourColor.B);` all the time. So it is usefull

Comment: Hard to understand what you think is ugly about code that's explicit.

Comment: @CodyGray: A major problem with writing out everything is that it's hardly visually obvious whether the intention and/or effect of the code will be to merely change `G`, or whether it will have other effects as well.  Given the design of the Color struct, I don't think there's any nice way to fix that; if there had been a simple `ArgbColor` struct with four exposed single-byte fields, and a `Color` class to which it was implicitly convertible, then `var temp = myColor.AsArgb(); temp.Green=100; myColor = temp;` would make clear that if e.g. `myColor` had been a named or system color...

Comment: ...that any such charateristics would be filtered out by the `AsArgb` method, but that any traits other than `Green` which had not been filtered out by that method would be retained.  Actually, if one defined an extension method to convert to the open-field structure type, that approach might be workable even with `Color` as defined, and might be the best way to do things.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue); //red, green and blue are integer variables containing red, green and blue components
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
public struct MyColor
    {
        private byte a, r, g, b;        
        public byte A
        {
            get
            {
                return this.a;
            }
        }
        public byte R
        {
            get
            {
                return this.r;
            }
        }
        public byte G
        {
            get
            {
                return this.g;
            }
        }
        public byte B
        {
            get
            {
                return this.b;
            }
        }       
        public MyColor SetAlpha(byte value)
        {
            this.a = value;
            return this;
        }
        public MyColor SetRed(byte value)
        {
            this.r = value;
            return this;
        }
        public MyColor SetGreen(byte value)
        {
            this.g = value;
            return this;
        }
        public MyColor SetBlue(byte value)
        {
            this.b = value;
            return this;
        }
        public int ToArgb()
        {
            return (int)(A << 24) || (int)(R << 16) || (int)(G << 8) || (int)(B);
        }
        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return string.Format ("[MyColor: A={0}, R={1}, G={2}, B={3}]", A, R, G, B);
        }

        public static MyColor FromArgb(byte alpha, byte red, byte green, byte blue)
        {
            return new MyColor().SetAlpha(alpha).SetRed(red).SetGreen(green).SetBlue(blue);
        }
        public static MyColor FromArgb(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
        {
            return MyColor.FromArgb(255, red, green, blue);
        }
        public static MyColor FromArgb(byte alpha, MyColor baseColor)
        {
            return MyColor.FromArgb(alpha, baseColor.R, baseColor.G, baseColor.B);
        }
        public static MyColor FromArgb(int argb)
        {
            return MyColor.FromArgb(argb & 255, (argb >> 8) & 255, (argb >> 16) & 255, (argb >> 24) & 255);
        }   
        public static implicit operator Color(MyColor myColor)
        {           
            return Color.FromArgb(myColor.ToArgb());
        }
        public static implicit operator MyColor(Color color)
        {
            return MyColor.FromArgb(color.ToArgb());
        }
    }
```